# How do you secure a RESTful API being consumed by a browser from CSRF attacks?

Tags: javascript, security, rest

I'm designing the API for a group of sites. The sites are very similar (kind of like StackOverflow, SuperUser and ServerFault), and it makes sense for them to have a shared backend. Hence we decided to try and have a nice REST API as a backend, and a bunch of very-similar-but-different frontends consuming said API. The frontends should preferably be all static, but that's not a hard requirement if it turns out to be borderline impossible.

I'm working on designing that API now, and I'm worried about the security implications, particularly CSRF. From my basic understanding of CSRF attacks, they consist of two important components:

1. Being able to name the resource and the request body.
2. Tricking the user/browser into using ambient auth (like sessions) to make a request to that resource that looks authenticated.

A lot of the classic approaches to fixing CSRF attacks are based on the session. Since my REST API doesn't really do sessions, that both prevents a lot of the vectors and also pretty much all of the ways to fix them. For example, double submitting doesn't make sense because there's nothing to double submit.

My initial approach involved attacking part 2 of a CSRF attack. If I authenticate all the requests (say using HTTP Basic Auth), and the browser doesn't keep those credentials stored (e.g. some JS made the request), only the JS that has the credentials can make the request, and we're done. The obvious downside is that the app needs to know the user's credentials. The other slightly less obvious downside is that if I want to store credentials securely on the API end, then verifying a password should take a fixed, non-trivial amount of time. If verifying a password securely takes 100ms, then every other request is going to take at least 100ms + eps, and it's going to take some darn clever clientside trickery to make that not feel slow. I might be able to cache that (since the credentials will always be the same), and if I'm very careful I might manage to do that without introducing a timing vulnerability, but that sounds like a hornet's nest.

OAuth 2.0 seems a bit over the top, but I guess it might be the best solution after all, lest I end up implementing it poorly. I suppose I could do the HTTP Basic Auth thing for now, and move to OAuth when we have third party app developers.

There's a bit of an impedance mismatch with OAuth. OAuth really wants to help apps access stuff on another app, basically. I want users to sign up on one of the frontends, before such an account even exists.

I've also considered attacking point 1 by making the URLs randomized -- ie adding tokens to a query string. This would certainly work and it's very close to how the traditional randomized token in a form works, and given HATEOAS it should even be fairly RESTful, although this raises two questions: 1) where do you start? Is there a mandatory API start point where you do log in using HTTP Basic Auth? 2) How much would it make app developers happy if they *can't* predict a URL up front, HATEOAS be damned?

I have seen [How to prevent CSRF in a RESTful application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392100/how-to-prevent-csrf-in-a-restful-application), but I disagree with the premise that randomized URIs are necessarily unRESTful. Also, that question doesn't really have any satisfactory answers, and doesn't mention OAuth. Also, the session double submit solution is invalid, as I've mentioned above (different domain for the static frontend than the API endpoint).

I realize that what I'm fundamentally trying to do here is trying to allow cross-site requests from one domain and disallow them from the other, and that's not easy. Surely there has to be some reasonable solution?

Comment: The problem, as you say, is that you want to both prevent and allow cross-site requests. Ask Schrödinger.

Comment: That doesn't mean there are no ways to solve the problem. I've even provided one that would, albeit a little slowly.

Answer (score 3):

A CSRF token is by definition "per user state" and therefore not RESTful.  Most API's break their "per user state" requirements for the purposes of security,  and require a CSRF token passed as an HTTP header parameter.

There are other ways of [preventing CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Checking the referer is not as strong as a CSRF token,  but it is RESTful and **VERY** unlikely to be undermined.  Keep in mind that the lack of a referer should be considered a failed request.

XSS can be used to bypass both token based CSRF prevention and referer based CSRF prevention.

Comment: Same remark as in my reply to your comment. Could you elaborate on why HTTP Basic Authentication doesn't prevent CSRF when you add the authentication header using JS? Also, how does OAuth not prevent CSRF? Doesn't the one time token part of OAuth guarantee that?

Comment: @lvh a user name and password is per-user state that is being sent with the request.  A Cryptographic Nonce used as a CSRF Token is also per user state sent with every request,  but it more secure because it should be a dynamic value tied to a session.   Usually RESTful protocols rely upon a static cryptographic nocne or "api key",  which is per-user state and also stops CSRF.  Sending it in the HTTP header doesn't magically make it restful,  but it can open the door to attack if other requests sent by that browser contain this value.

Comment: But that's my point. What's the attack vector if it doesn't become ambient browser auth? Whether it's a nonce or the actual credential doesn't matter for purposes of CSRF: the browser doesn't *know*, so how could it be tricked into providing it?

Comment: @ivh,  does that really need to be said?  Just prove that your assumptions are correct.

Comment: a csrf token put in httponly cookies can prevent XSS attack

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you need to support. If we assume that you want to support a  web-app which *uses* the REST service and use the same REST service for an API that is something different to a web-app that happens to be RESTFUL (you may decide that 'sessions' are for you! ).

For now (/me is rather tired) I think the way you have suggested using javascript with HTTP Basic Auth is a good start.

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth is vulnerable to CSRF.

Comment: Could you care to elaborate? I realize that browsers cache HTTP Basic Auth, but we're not asking the browser to do it; we're suggesting having some JS build the HTTP Basic Auth header. Hence the credentials never end up in the browser's ambient auth pool, and the system becomes CSRF-immune. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have another potential solution, so I'm listing it as an answer. Please feel free to take it apart :)

`auth.platform.com` takes authentication and sets cookies. If `auth.site.com` is a CNAME for `auth.platform.com`, would the request to `auth.site.com` (ending up at `auth.platform.com` after resolution) be able to set a cookie for `site.com`? That way I could double-submit session cookies.

Of course, `auth.platform.com` will only set cookies for a few whitelisted domains.

EDIT: Except of course this won't work at all, because you'd have to use HTTPS to do the authentication securely, and HTTPS will see right through your trickery.

Answer (score 0):

Designing your API as a true RESTful one, prevents the most common CSRF vectors:

- avoiding cookies prevents them to be "stolen",
- using GET for "safe" operations prevents `img` and `iframes` to trigger unsafe actions without user interaction.

Then you should implement [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to let users' browsers block requests from origins you don't trust.

Comment: Read on the [Mozilla developper network page about CSRF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSRF): "There are many ways to prevent CSRF, such as **implementing RESTful API**, adding secure tokens, etc.".

Comment: Read on the [Wikipedia page about CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery): "In HTTP GET the CSRF exploitation is trivial, using methods described above, such as a simple hyperlink containing manipulated parameters and automatically loaded by an IMG tag. By the HTTP specification however, **GET should be used as a safe method**, that is, not significantly changing user's state in the application. Applications using GET for such operations should switch to HTTP POST or use anti-CSRF protection."

Comment: GET should not incur a side-effect.  Even in a RESTful design - the POST method is intended to incur a side-effect and POST can be easily sent cross-site.  The problem I have with your answer is that I have seen developers implement POST and GET methods which make some kind of DB change or a configuration change that is exploitable via CSRF.