# Custom CSRF filter for Spring Security doesn't ignore my /login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm currently coding the security for a REST enterprise web application and when I finally got a custom CSRF filter work, I realised I can't POST anything into my /login because I need the CSRF token (a GET is possible though). The thing is, how can I retrieve for the first time the token so I can add it into the POST form that goes to the login?

I'm using postman as my REST client and the only way I can get the token is first doing a dummy GET so I can retrieve the token and then add it into the POST, but I'm here assuming this could not be like this.

I'm new to web security, csrf and also am not a front end developer, so the problem could lay there.

P.D: My security:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http    
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
        .and()
        .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenValiditySeconds(2000)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);

}
```

Also tried this one, but no good:

```
 @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
{
    webSecurity
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/login").anyRequest();

}
```

I'm using this custom filter, credits to the author: https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter

P.D.2: In case I wasn't clear enough, I want to login using a POST without doing the dummy get first. I don't know if is a code problem or a conceptual (security related) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration for authentication and CSRF are suitable for a browser based web app where you load the "login" page by GET request and then submit the credentials. This is why you can see the token after calling the GET request.

If you want to maintain session based CSRF protection, then you need to get the CSRF token with the initial GET request and use it with subsequent requests.

Here is a somewhat related thread - [How to prevent CSRF in a RESTful application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392100/how-to-prevent-csrf-in-a-restful-application)

Comment: So it was a conceptual problem after all. Two things more: it is secure that? I mean, any REST endpoint which receives a GET is gonna retrieve the CSRF token, even unauthenticated GETs (of course, without an authenticated cookie aka unauthenticated petitions response is a 401 error). Second: In a production release with its frontend, when I do the redirections and routing stuff, it's needed that a GET it's send to the server so it can retrieve the CSRF token first and then leave the user on the login menu? Or should the approach be different? I'm gonna vote the answer after this two are solved

Comment: The two concepts  and authentication) are related but different. CSRF is meant to ensure that all the calls come from the same source. That is, nobody can copy and reuse the URL without the token. Authentication is to make sure that the caller is

Comment: Authentication is still needed after CSRF to make sure that the caller is providing the right credentials and the session is authenticated. May not need CSRF for REST endpoint that doesnot need a session .

Comment: I thought so, but it's way better to be sure when security is at stake. Many thanks.