# How to prevent Rest web-service Authentication with stolen Token

Tags: java, rest, security, authentication, restful-authentication

As we know Rest services are stateless, General strategies to authenticate is using a token based authentication.

In login service it takes credentials which returns a token.

This token might be set in client cookies, and all subsequent requests uses this token to be validated and process new request if token is valid.

Now my question is how one can validate the token ? If someone has stolen the token and tries to access rest services with stolen token by just editing cookies then how can it be identified and restricted ?

We can never know if the token is fetched by valid user and same user is trying to access subsequent request. but what are the possible ways to make it more hard, like to verify if the request has came from same source ?

One general suggestion is to set aging for token/cookies, but it still not helpful till the age of that token/cookies.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the threat model here? How would a token be stolen and then abused?

Comment: @root Token is stored at client side cookies, it is possible that some other websites used through browser may fetch that cookies.

Comment: The browser doesn't allow just any site to access cookies from any other site. To steal cookies you need something more significant e.g. persistent XSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling through various approach We found a solution explained below:

1. We store token (encrypted) in cookies  on login request and for each subsequent request this cookie gets validated.
2. The problem was if someone replace the token in cookie with another valid token, as cookies are maintained by client browser.

Solution :-> Though token values were encrypted, it was representing only one value, So if one replace whole encrypted value with another valid encrypted value it can be hacked.

So to solve this we have added another cookie which was combination of multiple values.

e.g.

Cookie 1 -> encrypted token

Cookie 2 -> An encrypted object containing information like username+ some other user context details+token

So in case of Cookie 1, it was easy to replace with another encrypted value as it was representing only one token though it was encrypted.

But in case of Cookie 2, it was containing object with multiple values, so only token value can not be modified, encrypted and set back in same cookie.

Before authentication We are doing decryption whole cookie 2, fetch token part from it and validate the token part of it against cookie 1.

That has solved our problem !!

Thanks all for your time and guidance.

Answer (score 8):

I don’t believe there are any 100% fool proof methods of preventing access with stolen user tokens. How do you even know that the token is stolen in the first place? But from the top of my head you might want to consider following:

1. Accessing a REST service with the same token but a different user agent is suspicious. This can be recognized with the value of the User-Agent header. You might want to consider dropping such requests.
2. What if the IP address changes but the token is still the same? Well, maybe someone is using a load balancer and accesses the network over different IP addresses? Or he accessed a VPN with the same token/cookie as before? If you have no compunction dropping such requests, you might level up the security by checking the source IP address too.
3. In case of – say – JWT tokens, you will need a bit of infrastructure to handle the blacklisting. Follow [this](https://auth0.com/blog/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/).

Comment: In the UK well known ISPs change user IP addresses frequently - balance security with user experience

Comment: assigning bounty as it was expiring, and this answer was more relevant, but we have implemented a proper solution. I have explained the same in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

My current understand of the "most secure" approach to authorizing requests in the browser is to require validation of an HttpOnly SameSite cookie AND HTTP header (e.g. `Authorization` or `X-CSRF-Token`) in combination.

For example, when issuing the JWT to a browser, send the JWT signature in an `HttpOnly SameSite` cookie, and send the body (without signature) to the client to store in `localStorage` and submit in the `Authorization` header.  When authorizing a request, combine the two back into the complete JWT and validate it as normal after that.

Alternatively, you can generate two JWTs with a field to distinguish them (e.g. the client one has `"browser"` in it, the cookie has `"cookie"`) and require that both are valid and both identify the same user.  One is sent in the `Authorization` header and stored in `localStorage` and the other uses the `SameSite HttpOnly` cookie.

Another popular approach is to store a CSRF token in a field in the JWT, and put the JWT into a cookie and require the client to send a matching token in a header (e.g. `X-CSRF-Token`).

All of the solutions effectively prevent XSS and CSRF attacks: XSS cannot retrieve the HttpOnly cookie, and CSRF does not include the HTTP header, so this blocks both attacks.

Note that you probably only want to apply this rule for requests from web browsers.  For server-to-server communication, requests are not subject to CSRF and XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jwt is an Internet standard for creating JSON-based access tokens that assert some number of claims. For example, a server could generate a token that has the claim "logged in as admin" and provide that to a client. The client could then use that token to prove that it is logged in as admin .

How it's working ?

First it's contain private key generated by developer  :

let us have this key :`sfcqw@sav%$#fvcxv*s_s515` and this one called private key , and we also have a public key this the public key generated depended on user data and private key and it's impossible to know what is contain if you don't know the private key .

to more explain :

public key :

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.plpJkAcgrgCIsoRyV2kjGsvWF6OsXU1mD785OSWTH4o
```

we have the above key generated by our private key : `sfcqw@sav%$#fvcxv*s_s515`
[image]
To be more clear going to this website : https://jwt.io/ and try to past the public key without put secrite key like picture and you will understand everything .

Answer (score 0):

To me, there was no way to prevent the access from being stolen JWT token except

- setting a short timeout for the token
- more secured at the HTTP request level by only allowing specific `User-Agent. [See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)
- more secured at the HTTP request level by customizing the header key for the organization, e.g `My-X-Auth = Bearer <token>` instead of `Authorization= Bearer <token>`
- more secured at the HTTP request level by restricting trusted urls/domains, e.g `X-Content-Security-Policy`. [See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)